# How can I see my NFS share in any file manager on Android 6.0.1?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, file-sharing, cifs

I mounted my NFS shares successfully in Termux with busybox. I mounted the network folder to `/data/media/0/Music`.

I'm also able to see the content of the network share in the terminal with `ls -l /data/media/0/Music`. But when I click the location in my file manager the location is empty. I tried different file managers as well but all display nothing.

Is is a permission issue? What do I have to change in Android to make it work?

Comment: Did you create that mount as root? Then it might very well be a permission issue. What does `ls -l /data/media/0 | grep Music` show on ownership and permissions?

Comment: `ls -l /data/media/0 | grep Music` `says drwxr-xr-x 16 system system 4096 2016-08-27 20:58 Music`. I tried 2 ways to create the folder Music. 1. In File Manager as a normal user. When I was trying to access the folder after mounting I got a permission issue. 2. I created the folder in the termin as a root user. In that case the folder is displayed as empty in any File Manager.

Comment: OK, that says the folder is at least readable by everyone, and everyone can change into it (plus it belongs to the `system` user and group). Now please repeat the same with a minor adjustment: `ls -l data/media/0/Music/*` and pick a single entry from the output. If it has the same ownership (`system`), it should at least have 3 times "r" in it so other apps can read it.

Comment: All files in there have ownership `system` and all files have 3 times "r" in their permission properties. They should be readable by owner, group and others. But still I can't see any files in a File Manager or Music player app for my nfsv4 mount.

Comment: Not seeing them in the music player could have to do with the [media-scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) not having them picked up (yet). Nevertheless, that should not affect file managers, which confuses me. Have you tried 1) different file-managers, 2) examining that directory in a terminal with a non-privileged user (e.g. via `adb shell` as the "plain `shell` user")?

Comment: 1. Yes, I did try different file managers like CM File Manager v3.0.0, SolidExplorer v2.2.5 and Amaze v3.1.1. No success!
2. Examination of the folder structure with a non-privileged user via ADB gives me the following: `ls -l /data/media/0/Music` (Permission denied), `ls -l /storage/emulated/0/Music` (Permission denied) and `ls -l /sdcard/Music` gives me an 'empty' result. `ls -l /sdcard/ | grep Music` `gives me drwxrwx--x  2 root sdcard_rw     4096 2016-08-27 20:58 Music`.

Comment: I'm pretty much out of ideas then. Maybe the file manages must go via the "storage provider" for that directory? Or they don't belong to the `sdcard_rw` group? That then would explain them seeing nothing, as "others" can only change into the directory but not list its contents.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out an option in SuperSU blocked me from seeing the content of my mounts. I needed to disable the "Mount namespace separation" option in SuperSU app. Only then the mounts will be visible to other apps! Disabling namespace separation may cause security flaws, but I don't see any other solution yet. Reboot the device, mount your shares and everything will be as expected.

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611664